# What does j9T mean in yescrypt (from /etc/shadow)?

Tags: hash, scrypt

For example I have a shadow string

```
$y$j9T$PaFEMV0mbpeadmHDv0Lp31$G/LliR3MqgdjEBcFC1E.s/3vlRofsZ0Wn5JyZHXAol5
```

There are 4 parts

- id : y (yescrypt)
- param : j9T
- salt : PaFEMV0mbpeadmHDv0Lp31
- hash : G/LliR3MqgdjEBcFC1E.s/3vlRofsZ0Wn5JyZHXAol5

What does `j9T` in param field mean? Are there other options in this field?

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography.SE. I've asked for migration, however, I'll cancel that. Here from [unix.se](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/642570/70178) there it is on-topic here off-topic. I'm voting close this since it is about information about a password hashing system. It is better to be asked, unix.se, however, there are answers there for this. If the answers there doesn't satisfies you, you can ask there, however first, search there!

Comment: @kelalaka I have already read that topic but it only explained the param in scrypt and left the yescrypt case "an exercise for the reader". However, detailed materials of yescrypt does lack...
In addition, there is no yescrypt tag here. If you think it is a suitable tag here, please consider adding it.

Comment: As I've written, you can ask a new question thereby explaining that answer doesn't satisfy you. It is on-topic there not here.

Comment: I was a bit in two minds about this, but as there are now 4 close votes (which is a lot for this site) and since [kelalaka has reposted your question on the Unix site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/690679/102011) I'll use my vote to close this question, also because no answer seems to be forthcoming.